# Discord.js v12 Ban command which works but not banning the member

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this ban command which works but if I will say yes to complete the action it will give me an error that says:

`Error: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body DICT_TYPE_CONVERT: Only dictionaries may be used in a DictType`

I don't know what to do here at all because I have this same ban command for kick command just instead of `member.ban` it's `member.kick` and it works great with no errors.

```js
client.on('message', async message =>{
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + 'ban')) {
   if(!message.guild.member(client.user).hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('It seems like I dont have the permissions in this server.')
   if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
     return message.channel.send("You cant use this command since youre missing `ban_members` perm")}
   let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
let reason = args[1]
if(!reason) { reason = 'No provided' }

if(!member) return message.channel.send({embed: {description: 
`Please mention the member that you would like to ban`, color: "RANDOM", timestamp: new Date()}})
if(member.user.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send({embed: {description: `You cant ban yourself`, color: "RANDOM", timestamp: new Date()}})
if(!member.bannable) return message.channel.send({embed: {description: `I cant ban this user`, color: "RANDOM", timestamp: new Date()}})

message.channel.send( { embed: { description: `\`[20s]\` Are you sure you want ban ${member}? \`[yes/no]\``, color: 'YELLOW', timestamp: new Date() } } )

const collector = new MessageCollector(message.channel, msg => msg.author.id === message.author.id, {
    time: 20000
})

collector.on('collect', msg => {
  switch(msg.content) {
      case "yes":
          message.delete()
        if(member.bannable)
          member.ban(`reason: ${reason}`)
          .then(() => {
              collector.stop('success');
              return message.channel.send({embed:{description: 
`**${message.author.tag}** I have successfully banned \`${member.user.tag} (${member.user.id})\``, color: "RANDOM", timestamp: new Date()}})
          }).catch(err => {
              collector.stop('success');
              if (err) return message.channel.send({embed: {description: `Error: \`${err}\``, color: "RANDOM", timestamp: new Date()}})
          })
      break
      case "no":
          message.delete()
          message.channel.send({embed: {description: 
`**${message.author.tag}** since you said **no** i will go ahead and cancel this request`, color: "RANDOM", timestamp: new Date()}})
          collector.stop('success')   
      break
      default:
          message.delete()
          message.channel.send({embed: {description: 
`**${message.author.tag}** since you said **no** i will go ahead and cancel this request`, color: "RANDOM", timestamp: new Date()}})
          collector.stop('success')
    }
    collector.stop('success')
})
collector.on('end', (ignore, error) => {
    if (error && error !== "success") {
        return message.channel.send({embed: {description: 
`**${message.author.tag}** you ran out of time so i will go and cancel this request`, color: "RANDOM", timestamp: new Date()}})
    };
    collector.stop('success')
});
}})
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can use a string as the reason with `.kick()`, `.ban()` accepts an [object of options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) and you've provided a string instead (`reason: ${reason}`). It should be either `{reason: reason}`, or its shorthand form: `{ reason }`.

The following should work:

```js
// ...
.ban({ reason })
.then(...)
// ...
```

Comment: well i do i have member.ban(reason: reason) as u can see

Comment: No, you don't. That's a string in a template literal. Check it again.

Comment: ye you're right my bad. I've just been coding a lot today thanks a lot!

Comment: Haha, no problem :) If it solved your problem, don't forget to upvote/accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: of course, you are also the one who helped me with the clear command haha, you will get an upvote from me anytime.